# IP for virtual interface gets assigned to physical interface

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, ifconfig

I'm configuring a physical NIC and a virtual interface based on it as follows in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet manual
    post-up ifconfig eth0:1 hw ether 00:22:22:ff:ff:ff && dhclient eth0:1
```

where the MAC address `00:22:22:ff:ff:ff` is made up and doesn't occur in my LAN. As you can see I would like my DHCP server to manage the IP tricking it with the separate MAC address.

After a reboot I see in the output of `ifconfig` that `eth0:1` is not configured and that `eth0` has the IP which `eth0:1` gets when I run `sudo ifup eth0:1` manually after boot.

Configuring a static IP with `interfaces` stanza

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.178.27
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.178.1
```

works.

I'm using Linux 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: You can't have 2 different mac on a single physical interface...